# Only the first element of the ChartJS dataset is displayed

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Good afternoon! I have a large dataset to plot using ChartJS. The data is separated by time.
It seems that there are no errors, but only the first element is displayed. Please advise how to fix this problem.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    'labels': labels,
    datasets: r,
  },

  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: Math.max.apply(Math, r.map( o => o.data).flat())
      },
    },

    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'label'
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Legend'
    },
    responsive: true, 
    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mrjack/pen/ExpVOwb)

Comment: `data` in each dataset should be a valid values array. All of your datasets except first one are just filled with `null` values, so they are cannot be visible on chart.

Answer (score 0):

datasets: r,
what is the r ?
datasets must be has data.
sample dataset is,

```js
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "states",
                data: [120, 60 ,42 ,70, 60, 34, 70, 110, 120, 50],
                borderColor: ["rgb(255,0,200)"],
                backgroundColor: ["rgb(255,0,200,0.5)"],
              },
            ],
```

I figured out. thanks for the using codepen. I understand the problem. The problem is you used less labels on the chartjs. your data amount much more than labels. the second and third and other data are null at the beginning, for example, second data has 124 null at the begging. and your labels amount is 124. Chartjs created length of the 124 unit chart. therefore you could not see second data in your chart.
you use this labels array. You can figure out the problem easily.

```js
const labels = [
    "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
    "18:00",
    "18:15",
    "18:30",
    "18:45",
    "19:00",
    "19:15",
    "19:30",
    "19:45",
    "20:00",
    "20:15",
    "20:30",
    "20:45",
    "21:00",
    "21:15",
    "21:30",
    "21:45",
    "22:00",
    "22:15",
    "22:30",
    "22:45",
    "23:00",
    "23:15",
    "23:30",
    "23:45",
    "00:00",
    "00:15",
    "00:30",
    "00:45",
    "01:00",
    "01:15",
    "01:30",
    "01:45",
    "02:00",
    "02:15",
    "02:30",
    "02:45",
    "03:00",
    "03:15",
    "03:30",
    "03:45",
    "04:00",
    "04:15",
    "04:30",
    "04:45",
    "05:00",
    "05:15",
    "05:30",
    "05:45",
    "06:00",
    "06:15",
    "06:30",
    "06:45",
    "07:00",
    "07:15",
    "07:30",
    "07:45",
    "09:15",
    "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
      "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
    "18:00",
    "18:15",
    "18:30",
    "18:45",
    "19:00",
    "19:15",
    "19:30",
    "19:45",
    "20:00",
    "20:15",
    "20:30",
    "20:45",
    "21:00",
    "21:15",
    "21:30",
    "21:45",
    "22:00",
    "22:15",
    "22:30",
    "22:45",
    "23:00",
    "23:15",
    "23:30",
    "23:45",
    "00:00",
    "00:15",
    "00:30",
    "00:45",
    "01:00",
    "01:15",
    "01:30",
    "01:45",
    "02:00",
    "02:15",
    "02:30",
    "02:45",
    "03:00",
    "03:15",
    "03:30",
    "03:45",
    "04:00",
    "04:15",
    "04:30",
    "04:45",
    "05:00",
    "05:15",
    "05:30",
    "05:45",
    "06:00",
    "06:15",
    "06:30",
    "06:45",
    "07:00",
    "07:15",
    "07:30",
    "07:45",
    "09:15",
    "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
      "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
    "18:00",
    "18:15",
    "18:30",
    "18:45",
    "19:00",
    "19:15",
    "19:30",
    "19:45",
    "20:00",
    "20:15",
    "20:30",
    "20:45",
    "21:00",
    "21:15",
    "21:30",
    "21:45",
    "22:00",
    "22:15",
    "22:30",
    "22:45",
    "23:00",
    "23:15",
    "23:30",
    "23:45",
    "00:00",
    "00:15",
    "00:30",
    "00:45",
    "01:00",
    "01:15",
    "01:30",
    "01:45",
    "02:00",
    "02:15",
    "02:30",
    "02:45",
    "03:00",
    "03:15",
    "03:30",
    "03:45",
    "04:00",
    "04:15",
    "04:30",
    "04:45",
    "05:00",
    "05:15",
    "05:30",
    "05:45",
    "06:00",
    "06:15",
    "06:30",
    "06:45",
    "07:00",
    "07:15",
    "07:30",
    "07:45",
    "09:15",
    "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
      "09:30",
    "09:45",
    "10:00",
    "10:15",
    "10:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:00",
    "11:15",
    "11:30",
    "11:45",
    "12:00",
    "12:15",
    "12:30",
    "12:45",
    "13:00",
    "13:15",
    "13:30",
    "13:45",
    "14:00",
    "14:15",
    "14:30",
    "14:45",
    "15:00",
    "15:15",
    "15:30",
    "15:45",
    "16:00",
    "16:15",
    "16:30",
    "16:45",
    "17:00",
    "17:15",
    "17:30",
    "17:45",
    "18:00",
    "18:15",
]
```

Comment: the data set is presented https://codepen.io/mrjack/pen/ExpVOwb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I figured out. thanks for the using codepen. I understand the problem. The problem is you used less labels on the chartjs. your data amount much more than labels. the second and third and other data are null at the beginning, for example, second data has 124 null at the begging. and your labels amount is 124. Chartjs created length of the 124 unit chart. therefore you could not see second data in your chart. I expended labels array with mockup data, now you can see.